# Spring Security User Roles Per Organization

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my application I have a top level entity called Organization.  The relationship between User and Organization is many-to-many.

Because of this I could have the following scenario:

- UserA has role ROLE_ADMIN for OrganizationA
- UserA has role ROLE_USER for OrganizationB

I need to ensure that when UserA accesses resources for OrganizationB he is not doing it as an ADMIN.  So I need an additional check that the user has the correct roles at the organization level.  Is there anything built into Spring Security that allows for this?  If not, does anyone know what the best way would be to about solving this?

UPDATE: A bit more information...

A User logs in and chooses which org they want to work with.  That is stored in the session.  Beyond that, URLs are locked down with the Secured annotation.  What that means is that if UserA were to log in and select OrgA, they should be able to access /admin/user/create however, if they log in and choose OrgB they should not have access to that URL.

The long way is to add additional checks in every method where this matters.  So call some service method that says "ok, you're an admin for OrgA but not for OrgB and you're logged in using OrgB, so deny this request".

I'm hoping for a more grails / spring-security way of handling this.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide some more information here, otherwise it's difficult to suggest a concrete approach. What differentiates between resources for different organizations, for example?

Comment: As an admin or OrganizationA I can create users.  I don't want to allow that for UserA on OrganizationB.  That kind of stuff.

Comment: Ok, what I should probably have said is "How does your app differentiate between different resources?" What is "a resource" in this context? Do you use different URLs for different orgs, for example?

Comment: I've updated my question to add this bit of detail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this by using a custom `AccessDecisionVoter`. The `vote` method will supply you with the "configuration attributes" for the resource (method or URL), which will typically be the required roles, and you can obtain the current user's roles/authorities either directly from the `Authentication` object, or by reading the current org and selecting the appropriate roles for the user.

I'm assuming that you have some way of differentiating the user's roles, based on the org they've selected.

Essentially, you'd be writing an extended version of the standard [`RoleVoter`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/254333ce825c79ae4500c5f0c6ec7d7dfae0b306/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.java), which takes the organization into account.

Comment: Ah, ok.  This makes sense.  I'll give a go and report back.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm little late here but this is what worked for me:

When an organization is selected, you can set a new Authentication object with new roles in your session(The previous Authentication object gets invalidated). Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/org-a")
String orgA(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("org", "org-a")
    Organization org = new Organization("org-a")
    reloadRolesForAuthenticatedUser(org)
    ....
}

private void reloadRolesForAuthenticatedUser(Organization org) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
    List<String> newRoles = getRoles(auth.getPrincipal().getUsername(), org)
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getAuthorities(newRoles)
    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(),auth.getCredentials(),authorities)
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth)
}


private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>()
    if (!roles.isEmpty()) {
        for (String r : roles) {
            auths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r))
        }
    }
    return auths
}
```