# Custom RoleVoter And Accessing UserRole for additional vote check

Tags: grails, spring-security

Taking the suggestion provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875042/spring-security-user-roles-per-organization), I've implemented my own RoleVoter classes that extends RoleVoter and the additional check I need to add is that the User, Role, and Organization all line up based on the Organization I have stored in the session.

I have the following UserRole class:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {
  User user
  Role role
  Organization organization
  ....
}
```

And this is my OrganizationRoleVoter class:

```
class OrganizationRoleVoter extends RoleVoter {

  @Override
  public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {

    int result = ACCESS_ABSTAIN
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = extractAuthorities(authentication)

    attributes.each {ConfigAttribute attribute ->
      if (this.supports(attribute)) {
        result = ACCESS_DENIED

        authorities.each {GrantedAuthority authority ->
          //TODO this should also check the chosen organization
          if (attribute.attribute.equals(authority.authority)) {
            return ACCESS_GRANTED
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication.getAuthorities();
  }

}
```

As you can see in my TODO, this is where I need to also say "is the authority that is being granted here also in line with the organization that I've placed in the session.  Really at a loss on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I've solved it thus far.  This seems to work but I'm always open for improvements:

```
class OrganizationRoleVoter extends RoleVoter {

  @Override
  public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {

    int result = ACCESS_ABSTAIN
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = extractAuthorities(authentication)
    GrailsWebRequest request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
    Organization selectedOrganization = (Organization) request.session.getAttribute("selectedOrganizationSession")

    attributes.each {ConfigAttribute attribute ->
      if (this.supports(attribute)) {
        result = ACCESS_DENIED
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
          if (attribute.attribute.equals(authority.authority)) {
            def user = User.findByUsername(authentication.name)
            def role = Role.findByAuthority(authority.authority)
            if (UserRole.findByUserAndOrganizationAndRole(user, selectedOrganization, role)) {
              result = ACCESS_GRANTED
              break
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication.getAuthorities();
  }

}
```